# what is branching factor in b tree

Tags: database, data-structures, filesystems, rdbms

Recently when I was doing my assignment I got through this question

Calculate branching factor in case for B-tree index structure, 
  given:
(page size: 16 KB, key-size: 16 bytes, pointer size = 8 bytes)

```
255

256

510

511
```

I am actually confused which answer to pick because

I know that if order of a b tree is  'b' then branching factor is in between b+1 and 2*b+1

but when I actually calculate the value it turns out to be like

if b+1 to be considered then it is 256 and if 2*b+1 then it will be 511

I am really confused which option to pick because as far as my knowledge is considered the branching factor can be any  value between b+1 and 2*b+1 and so now all options seem to be correct

can the folks there can help me out, am I missing any concept ?

Answer (score 0):

The Branching Factor is

```
2*b+1
```

This is because an internal node can have max number of child nodes in a B-tree.

for at most `2*b+1`, for at least `b+1`